# How can I time scraping news stories from a list of urls with R?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to download the text of newspaper articles for textual analysis using R. I have a large list of urls to individual articles and want to use Rvest to extract each of these articles' text and title and convert it into a data frame.

As an example, I have a subset of my dataset with articles from The Guardian:

```
> items$link[1:8]

[1] "https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2019/nov/16/concerns-raised-cladding-bolton-student-building-fire"                                   
[2] "https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2019/nov/16/top-lawyer-calls-prince-andrew-bbc-interview-catastrophic-error"                         
[3] "https://www.theguardian.com/politics/live/2019/nov/16/general-election-labour-meet-decide-manifesto-clause-v-live-news"                  
[4] "https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/nov/16/priti-patel-block-rescue-british-isis-children"                                         
[5] "https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/nov/16/police-assessing-claims-that-tories-offered-peerages-to-brexit-party"                   
[6] "https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/nov/16/paris-police-fire-teargas-on-anniversary-of-gilets-jaunes-protests"                        
[7] "https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2019/nov/16/trump-personally-kept-pressure-ukraine-impeachment-inquiry-witness-david-holmes-diplomat"
[8] "https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/nov/16/hong-kong-chinese-troops-deployed-to-help-clear-roadblocks"
```

My code so far is:

```
## SETUP ##
rm(list=ls())
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(readtext)
library(quanteda)
library(beepr)

setwd("uk")

## Functions ##
parse_texts <- function(nod){
  body <- str_squish(as.character(nod) %>% read_html() %>%
                       html_nodes('.js-article__body > p') %>% #collects all text in article
                       html_text())
  one_body <- paste(body, collapse = " ") # puts all of the text together
  data.frame(title = str_squish(nod %>% read_html() %>% 
                                  html_node('.content__headline') %>% 
                                  html_text()),
             date_time = str_squish(nod %>% read_html() %>% 
                                      html_node('.content__dateline-wpd--modified') %>% 
                                      html_text()),
             text = one_body,
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

#extract file text
test_df <- lapply(items$link[1:5], parse_texts) %>% bind_rows()
```

This works, for the most part. My problem is that I have thousands of urls in my data. How can I automate a script that will slowly work through this list?

Comment: So what's wrong with this method? It's too fast?

Comment: I believe that going to the same news site too many times too fast will get my IP address banned.

Comment: You can add `Sys.sleep()` inside your function to slow down the parsing, a 1 to 2 second pause should prevent you from violating any quotas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Dave2e for answering the question.

I added `Sys.sleep(2)` to the `parse_texts` function and was able to go through my list of URLs.